# Could not load type 'XXXX.aaa'

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

[image][image: Error]

Hi,

I am having Could not load type error when I release my code into live environment. If I remove the code Inherits="CheckIEBrowser.Check" that gets rid of the error, it displays the page, but it doesn't work as it should.

Thanks in advance

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CheckIEBrowser
{
    public partial class Check : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(IsPostBack))
            {
```

...

Comment: Please clean and rebuild your project solution.

Comment: how was the Check.aspx.cs file added to the project..? did you do it creating it in the IDE or manually.. also show us the .cs file.. are you using namespace ...?

Comment: I have deleted everything inside the bin folder and rebuilt but still the error persists

Comment: I add check.aspx manually buy adding a new file from VS2013, add new item, web form

Comment: Dumb question, but did you copy the dll files to the server?

Comment: Yes I copied all dll files

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of Check.aspx and its CS fle to your local

Delete Check.aspx and Check.aspx.cs manually from directory

Clean Solution

Right click your solution add new form and name it as Check.aspx

Copy your local saved check.aspx contents to Check.aspx that we created newly (except line 1 )

do the same for check.aspx.cs also

rebuild your solution

Than try

if its not work, delete CheckIEBrowser.sln file and try